# Repeated filtering on Spark Dataframe?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a large Spark dataframe that contains a variety of financial information, say the schema looks something like:

```
Amount

account_id | amount
0            10.00
1            15.15
...
```

I have another large Spark dataframe that contains payment information, which is supposed to represent a payment towards that amount. For example

```
Payment

account_id | paid_amount
0            5.00
0            5.00
1            15.15
```

What I want to do is to iterate through each unique ID in my amount dataframe, and one at a time, filter out the payments that were associated with that ID in order to perform some other calculations.

Is this a slow operation or ill-advised? It seems like looping through all these Account IDs in a linear fashion is throwing away a lot of the optimization that Spark is providing.

What would be a better alternative, should one exist?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Join both the dataframes and perform your complex operations on them

```
Df=Amountdf.join(paymentdf, 'id','inner')
```

Comment: Thanks Shubham -- I was considering this but wondered if there are any negative implications depending on the sizes of the DFs? For example, if each contained millions of rows, would it still be a good idea to join them up front?

Comment: Yes joining will be one time heavy lifting while iterating is nowhere in picture if you are using spark. Also if you are using spark 3.0 the AQE will take care of the join else you have to manually optimize the join for better performance

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can approach this problem.

Make both DataFrames as small as possible (e.g. perhaps run `payments_df.groupBy("account_id").sum()`, write them out to disk and see which one is smaller.

If one of the DataFrames is small enough to be broadcasted, just do a broadcast join with `big_df.join(broadcast(small_df), "id", "inner")`.  See here for more details on [broadcast joins](https://mungingdata.com/apache-spark/broadcast-joins/).

If you can use Spark 3, try the join and see if [Adaptive Query Execution](https://databricks.com/blog/2020/05/29/adaptive-query-execution-speeding-up-spark-sql-at-runtime.html) gives you the performance you need.

If that's not good enough, look at [optimizing a sort merge join](https://medium.com/datakaresolutions/optimize-spark-sql-joins-c81b4e3ed7da#:%7E:text=To%20accomplish%20ideal%20performance%20in%20Sort%20Merge%20Join%3A&text=Make%20sure%20the%20partitions%20have,stored%20in%20the%20same%20partition.).

Definitely don't iterate over rows in a DataFrame one-by-one!